# What are the variable RSA * and BIO * in Openssl function?

Tags: openssl

In this openssl function;  int RSA_generate_key_ex(RSA *rsa, int bits, BIGNUM *e, BN_GENCB *cb);
I dont know what is RSA *rsa, I can't get documentation
i saw that use a variable BIO * and can't get documentation for this too

Comment: Im using openssl@1.1, i cant found documentation for this

Comment: **The short all-cap names in OpenSSL are typedefs** (or in a few cases #define's for typedefs) declared in ossl_typ.h which exists on the system where you compile or [here in github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h) and is itself #include'd by the 'visible' header files that the man pages document e.g. rsa.h [here on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_generate_key_ex.html).